# php7 interface defining return type gives error

Tags: php, php-7

I have created `TestInterface`. I have specified the type for all parameters and it works well.

```
interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * 조건에 따른 질의에 대해 레코드 수를 반환한다.
     * @param  [type]  $where  [where 구문]
     * @param  boolean $isLike [like 여부]
     * @return [type]          [description]
     */
    public function allCount(array $where, bool $isLike, bool $join);
}
```

However, when I specify return type, it gives me 500 error. Isn't specifying return type supported in php 7? If it does, please give me advice how to do it. If not, how do I make custom function which works like `define return type`?

```
interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * 조건에 따른 질의에 대해 레코드 수를 반환한다.
     * @param  [type]  $where  [where 구문]
     * @param  boolean $isLike [like 여부]
     * @return [type]          [description]
     */
    public function allCount(array $where, bool $isLike, bool $join) : int;
}
```

And `allCount` method always returns `int` type.

Comment: Without seeing your implementation of the interface it is a little hard to debug. Does the implementation include the return type hint as well? The documentation for return values (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) states "When overriding a parent method, the child's method must match any return type declaration on the parent. If the parent doesn't define a return type, then the child method may do so.".

Comment: @Matt Rink
Thank you for the comment. Like you said, its really hard to debug since there are many methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem....

I am using the method `allCount` on 40 files. But only one of them returns array type.